# What proxy server can I install real quick on Windows Server Web Edition?

Tags: windows, proxy, firewall

I need to install really quick a proxy server at Windows Server 2008 WEB EDITION. Could you recommend one?

Of course the server have access to the internet, I want to make the server work as a proxy with credential in order for me to navigate the Internet through it by just configuring my proxy settings at Internet Explorer.

Thanks in advanced,

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.winproxy.net/ . It should work even on the Web Edition.